# How to serve Spring Boot App using IntelliJ within local network?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm developing a Spring Boot application using IntelliJ. The run configuration (Run > Edit Configurations...) is of type `Spring Boot`. The `Run on:` option is set to `Local machine`. Everything is working fine so far. I can perfectly access the application from the developing machine at `localhost:8080`.

### My question is:

What do I have to do to access this application during development from within my local network?

Since this is a web application, I want to test the design-interface not only from the development machine but also from other devices like IPad or mobile phones. Unfortunately just replacing `localhost:8080` with the local IP of the machine `192.168.x.x:8080` won't work to gain access.

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: This approach is correct for local network. It works for me. Spring Boot application on Windows 7 and mobile phone Android over WiFi. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Mar-Z many thanks for that information. Thanks to that and thus knowing the issue is on my side, I could figure out that a combination of vpn, firewall and IntelliJ itself were the culprits. It seems, at least in my case, I first have to setup the vpn and fw correctly and afterwards! start the IDE so that IntelliJ can pickup correct settings during its startup. MANY THANKS AGAIN